# Connecting to SQL Server with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, odbc, windows-server-2016

I am trying to connect to views in a SQL Server DB in Arcatalog / Arcmap.
I am using the "Database Connections\Add Database Connection" method in catalog.
I can connect fine but cannot see / preview data in catalog. 
It's not an SDE database, but another company DB.

I have a suspicion it’s a driver issue (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) but I get lost about what to use and how to get these files / install them (32 bit or 64 bit etc.)

**SQL specs:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

**Arc specs:**
ArcgGIS 10.5.0.6491

Windows 10

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what type of database it is? My gut tells me if you connect fine, it is not a driver issue.

Comment: @TJBara it is a SQL Server 2016 DB as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Does your user have the permissions to see the data?  What makes you think it's a driver issue?  Don't just give a link - be specific please. If you can connect without error it doesn't sound like a driver issue to me.

Comment: How have you established the connection?  A direct connect to the SQL Server?  Or via ODBC?  Please [edit] your question to include any additional information and response to comments.

Answer (score 1):

@TJBara - you were correct, I could connect fine so this rules out any driver issue.

It ended up being some security or privilege on the DB - basically, it didn't like ESRI or the ODBC connection viewing the data (?). My workaround was to create a view pointing to the views on another DB (same server) and this worked. This was actually a better way to do it anyway - rather than creating views on the production DB.